# Execute command defined by backreference in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am creating a primitive experimental templating engine completely based on sed (merely for my private enjoyment). One thing I have been trying to achieve for several hours now is to replace certain text patterns with the output of a command they contain.

To clearify, if an input line looks like this

```
Lorem {{echo ipsum}}
```

I would look the sed output to look like this:

```
Lorem ipsum
```

The closest I have come is this:

```
echo 'Lorem {{echo ipsum}}' | sed 's/{{\(.*\)}}/'"$(\\1)"'/g'
```

which does not work.

However,

```
echo 'Lorem {{echo ipsum}}' | sed 's/{{\(.*\)}}/'"$(echo \\1)"'/g'
```

gives me

```
Lorem echo ipsum
```

I don't quite understand what is happening here. Why can I give the backreference to the echo command, but cannot evaluate the entire backreference in $()? When is \\1 getting evaluated? Is the thing I am trying to achieve even possible with pure sed?

Keep in mind that it is entirely clear to me that what I am trying to achieve is easily possible with other tools. However, I am highly interested in whether this is possible with pure sed.

Thanks!

Comment: You aren't passing the expansion to `echo`. `echo` is seeing and echoing the literal `\1`. Run `set -x` before running that line to see it. And no, you cannot do what you want with any version of `sed` that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your attempt doesn't work is that `$()` is expanded by the shell before `sed` is even called. For this reason it can't use the backreferences `sed` is eventually going to capture.

It is possible to do this sort of thing with GNU sed (not with POSIX sed). The main trick is that GNU sed has a `e` flag to the `s` command that makes it replace the pattern space (the whole space) with the result of the pattern space executed as a shell command. What this means is that

```
echo 'echo foo' | sed 's/f/g/e'
```

prints `goo`.

This can be used for your use case as follows:

```
echo 'Lorem {{echo ipsum}}' | sed ':a /\(.*\){{\(.*\)}}\(.*\)/ { h; s//\1\n\3/; x; s//\2/e; G; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1\3/; ba }'
```

The `sed` code works as follows:

```
:a                                    # jump label for looping, in case there are
                                      # several {{}} expressions in a line
/\(.*\){{\(.*\)}}\(.*\)/ {            # if there is a {{}} expression,
  h                                   # make a copy of the line
  s//\1\n\3/                          # isolate the surrounding parts
  x                                   # swap the original back in
  s//\2/e                             # isolate the command, execute, get output
  G                                   # get the outer parts we put into the hold
                                      # buffer
  s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1\3/    # rearrange the parts to put the command
                                      # output into the right place
  ba                                  # rinse, repeat until all {{}} are covered
}
```

This makes use of `sed`'s greedy matching in the regexes to always capture the last `{{}}` expression in a line. Note that it will have difficulties if there are several commands in a line and one of the later ones has multi-line output. Handling this case will require the definition of a marker that the commands embedded in the data are not allowed to have as part of their output and that the templates are not allowed to contain. I would suggest something like `{{{}}}`, which would lead to

```
sed ':a /\(.*\){{\(.*\)}}\(.*\)/ { h; s//{{{}}}\1{{{}}}\3/; x; s//\2/e; G; s/\(.*\)\n{{{}}}\(.*\){{{}}}\(.*\)/\2\1\3/; ba }'
```

The reasoning behind this is that the template engine would run into trouble anyway if the embedded commands printed further `{{}}` terms. This convention is impossible to enforce, but then any code you pass into this template engine had better come from a trusted source, anyway.

Mind you, I am not sure that this whole thing is a sane idea<sup>1</sup>. You're not planning to use it in any sort of production code, are you?

<sup>1</sup>I am, however, quite sure *whether* it is a sane idea.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I am just experimenting with sed and building this thing out of curiosity to get more familiar with it - no production usage planned here.